# Unreadable content message with Jasper and .xlsx

Tags: java, stream, jasper-reports, xlsx

I have the following code that exports a xlsx to a stream. It works and I get the xlsx file but it says excel found unreadable content in "..." and asks if I want to recover the contents of the workbook. When I do so, I get the xlsx file with the correct data, in the correct places, as I wanted. How can I avoid or supress this error?

```
try {
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                .compileReport(path
                        + "Template/Instructions_with_CHGFOX_Template/testeXlsx2.jrxml");

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));

        JRXlsxExporter xlsxExporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        xlsxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
        xlsxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
                title + ".xlsx");

        xlsxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,
                servletOutputStream);

        xlsxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outStream);
        xlsxExporter.exportReport();

        resp.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + title + ".xlsx");

        servletOutputStream.write(outStream.toByteArray());

        resp.getOutputStream().write(outStream.toByteArray());
        resp.getOutputStream().flush();
        resp.getOutputStream().close();
        resp.flushBuffer();

    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

using using JasperReports v4.7.1

[UPDATE]
tried for when no data type the following options
No pages, Blank Page, All Sections No Detail and No Data Section
none of them worked

also tried adding thing to my web.xml

```
<mime-mapping>
<extension>xlsx</extension>
<mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-          officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

finally tried closing my outStream which didn't work either, excel still says unreadable content

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with the XLSX (but not xls) exporter when

1. The report prints no pages when there's no data
2. The data list is empty.

Inspect your data list and set your report to print something other than "no pages" (e.g. no data section or all sections without detail).

Comment: How do I print something else than no pages when there's no data?

Comment: If you're designing in ireport, you can set it in report properties (right click on the topmost node in report inspector) or adding an attribute to the root <jasperReport> element, like <jasperreport whenNoDataType="NoDataSection">

Comment: I'm using JasperSoft Studio and I have in my properties "when do data type -> Blank page"

Comment: I guess you can alter it to some other value like "No Data Section". see http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534461/how-use-no-data-band

Comment: I tried that as well. I tried the following options No pages, Blank Page, All Sections No Detail and  No Data Section

Answer (score 1):

This means the report had no data. To fix the bad file message simply add the NoData section to your report with a meaningful message.

Comment: you mean making an if, if I have no data?

Comment: You do not need to specify a condition. The NoData section is printed instead all the other bands when the report row count is zero.

Comment: I selected Blank Page when no data type and still got the same problem

Comment: In the report When no data property you should specify No Data Section and then enable the No Data band.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (reportType.equals("excel")) {
        try {

            ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = resp
                    .getOutputStream();
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(path + "Template/" + template);

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                    parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));

            JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, os);
            exporter.exportReport();
            resp.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ title + ".xlsx");
            resp.getOutputStream().write(os.toByteArray());
            resp.flushBuffer();

        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
```